# Query about Reductio Ad Absurdum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

If we use the method of contradiction(i.e.Reductio Ad Absurdum), and if one of our assumptions is wrong, does that mean that all our assumptions are wrong and is the statement or hypothesis proved?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It sounds kind of like you think "a and b have common factors other than 1" and "a/b is in reduced form" don't directly contradict each other, but they do.

Comment: In general, with *RAA* we may choose what is the assumption "to be blamed", i.e. what is the assumption to be discarded. If more than one, we do not have to discarde all them. But it is not clear to me your question; you assume that $\sqrt 2$ is *rational*; then derive a contradiction. Finally, apply *RAA* and conclude that the assumption : "$\sqrt 2$ is *rational*" must be discarded.

Comment: @rschwieb No, there are two: (1) $\sqrt{2}$ is in the form of p/q and (2) p and q have no common factors.

Comment: It's a valid initial assumption, since if we have $\frac ab$ where $\gcd(a, b) = d\neq 1$, then we simply choose $\frac{a/d}{b/d} = \dfrac pq$. Every rational number can be written in reduced form, and if $\sqrt 2$ is rational, it *too* could be written in the form $p/q$, $\gcd(p, q) = 1$.

Comment: Ok. I think I picked the wrong example. I will edit it. But what about other proofs which are proved in the same way?

Comment: The "no common factor" is not really an *assumption*; we apply a theorem which says that to every rational $p/q$ we can apply a specified "procedure" (an algorithm) which, in a finite number of steps, reduce it to "no common factor". Thus, for simplicity, we "mentally apply" this procedure.

Comment: @Yashbhatt The point about "$a$ and $b$ have no common factors" does not have to be viewed as an assumption. Assuming that $\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$ for some $a$ and $b$, you can *prove* that you can replace $a$ and $b$ with $a'$ and $b'$ having no common factor such that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'}$. This follows from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct: once we obtain a contradiction, we don't know which of our assumptions was false.  Any or all of them might be.  But the claim that $a$ and $b$ have no common factor is not an assumption.

In the proof that $\sqrt2$ is irrational, we start by supposing that $\sqrt2$ is rational.  A rational number is one that can be written as a fraction, so we have $\sqrt2 = \frac pq$  for some integers $p$ and $q$, and $q\ne 0$.

Now what if $p$ and $q$ had a common factor?  Then we could take the fraction $$\sqrt2 = \frac pq$$ and cancel the common factor from the numerator and denominator and obtain an equal fraction $$\sqrt 2 = \frac ab$$ which was in lowest terms.  And then $a$ and $b$ would have no common factor greater than 1, because that is what it means to write a fraction in lowest terms.  Since *every* fraction can be written in lowest terms, we can do this no matter what $p$ and $q$ were.

So *if* $\sqrt 2$ is rational, we *can* find integers $a$ and $b$ with $\sqrt2=\frac ab$ and $a$ and $b$ have no common factor bigger than 1.  This is not an assumption; it's how fractions work.

And if we get nonsense later on, that they have common factors anyway, we know it must be nonsense.  It couldn't be because $a$ and $b$ had a common factor bigger than 1, because we know there must be *some* pair of integers  that don't have a common factor bigger than 1; we can obtain them by reducing the original fraction to lowest terms, and then call them $a$ and $b$.  It can't actually be that $a$ and $b$ really had a common factor all along, because if there had been one, we would already have canceled the factor and used the names $a$ and $b$ for the result instead.  So the problem must be something else.

Comment: I agree that I chose the wrong example. But I am asking about the general cases. If for any other proof we have more than 1 assumptions, then is it enough to prove one of them wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you agree you chose the wrong example. I didn't say you chose the wrong example, so who are you agreeing with?  And didn't I address the general case in the first paragraph of my answer?  I'm not sure what else can be said in general.

Comment: By wrong example I mean that it is true that it contains only one assumption. And you said we don't know. Any or all of them _might_ be.

Comment: I accept that gcd(a,b)=1 is not an assumption. You are just saying that $\sqrt{2}=p/q \implies \sqrt{2}=a/b$, that's also fine. But the question is how the contradiction of $\sqrt{2}=a/b$ implies the contradiction of $\sqrt{2}=p/q$.

Comment: It is a general principle of logic that if $A$ implies $B$, and $B$ is false, then $A$ is false also.

Comment: In fact, the meaning of "$A$ implies $ B$" is precisely that $A$ proves anything that $B$ proves. In particular,  if $B$ proves a contradiction then so does $A$.

Comment: "if **A** implies **B**, and **B** is false, then **A** is false also": Is it an axiom in Mathematics or it can be proved?

Comment: That depends on what your axioms are.

Comment: @MJD I do not know what my axioms are. I somehow am not able to accept that "if truth of $A\implies$truth of B" then "falsification of B $\implies$ falsification of A". I've found what I wanted. I needed the term _contraposition_. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition#Simple_proof_by_contradiction) I found the general proof(quite similar to what I been doing in [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1020278/103816) ). There are also other proofs which I wanted to know.

Comment: @MJD Could you tell me some reference or something which gives the mathematical definition of the term _implies_.

Comment: [Re, 6th comment on this post] I do not think that in our case $B$ is proving a contradiction. Here $B$ in itself is found to be contradicted, or more precisely the statement "B is true" is contradicted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. However:

The only assumption made is that $p/q$ has no common factors, and then this is contradicted by showing that they must.

This means that $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as a reduced fraction (i.e. with no common factors in $p$ and $q$). Since *every* fraction can be written in reduced form, there is *no* fraction equal to $\sqrt{2}$ - it does not help to switch to "another" fraction $a/b$.

Comment: Ok. I get for this proof. But if for some other proof, we have a number of assumptions, is it enough to prove one of them wrong to prove a statement?