# Understanding the proof of "$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational" by contradiction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-verification, radicals, rationality-testing

I have some difficulties in understanding the proof of "$\sqrt{2}$is irrational" by contradiction. I am reading it in 10th class(in India) Mathematics book( available online, [here](http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/textbook/textbook.htm?jemh1=1-14) )

This is the snapshot of it:

[image: im-1][image: im2]

The proof starts with assuming that $\sqrt{2}$ can be written as a ratio of two integers and then that this fraction can be reduced to its lowest terms i.e. $\sqrt{2}=\dfrac ab$, where gcd(a,b)=1 . Then at last we reach at the contradiction that gcd$(a,b)\neq1$. Then they say that because of this contradiction $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be a rational number.

What I do not understand is that how the contradiction proves that $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be a rational number. The contradiction only proves that $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as the ratio of two coprime numbers. But can't we write $\sqrt{2}$ as the ratio of two non-coprime numbers?

Let us consider two statements, X and Y as:

> **X**: $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as the ratio of two coprime numbers.
>
> **Y**: $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as the ratio of two non-coprime numbers.

The contradiction proves only the statement X not the statement Y.

I guess that we can prove statement Y from X as:
Let us suppose that $\sqrt{2}$ can be written as the ratio of two non-coprime numbers, i.e. $\sqrt{2}=\dfrac RS$, where $R$ and $S$ are mutually non-coprime. But every rational number can be written as a  fraction *in lowest terms*. So let's say $\dfrac RS$ in its lowest terms is $\dfrac rs$, but this means that $\sqrt{2}$ is also equal to $\dfrac rs$, where $r$ and $s$ are coprime. This eventually  contradicts the statement **X**, hence by contradiction $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as the ratio of two non-coprime numbers, or the statement **Y** is true.

**Question:**

**1. Did I prove the statement Y from X correctly ?**

**2. Why does the book directly mention "$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational" without justifying statement Y? Is the justification too trivial to be mentioned?**

**3. Is there any other way than mine(proof by contradiction) to deduce Y from X?**

I only want to clarify these three doubts, nothing else.

Comment: Y can (trivially) be reduced to statement X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query about Reductio Ad Absurdum](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812723/query-about-reductio-ad-absurdum).  (The title does't suggest it, but that person's question is just like yours, and my answer to that question is just what I would say to you.  Key point: “The claim that $a$ and $b$ have no common factor is not an assumption.”)

Comment: Every rational number can be written uniquely as a fraction in "lowest terms".

Comment: @MJD thank you for the link, I am reading it.

Comment: @fvel do you mean that Y can be reduced to X without any proof?

Comment: @user31782 If you have two numbers $a_c$ and $b_c$ $\frac{a_c}{b_c}$ are not coprime and share a factor $c$, you can cancel away the $c$ and reduce it to the coprime one where $\frac{a}{b}$ is an irreducible fraction. This can be done for any reducible fraction $\frac{x}{y}$ where $x$ and $y$ are not comprime, and this is why one would only consider an irreducible fraction.

Comment: @fvel you mean that the statement "k=a_c/b_c where a and b are non-co prime" implies "k can be written as a/b s.t. a and b are coprime". But how does the statement "√2 **cannot** be written as the ratio of two coprime numbers." implies "√2 cannot be written as the ratio of two non-coprime numbers."?

Comment: @MJD I've read your answer there. I still do not understand how **X $\implies$ Y**.

Comment: @user31782 If it could be written as two non-coprime numbers, that would be equivalent to being possible to write it as two coprime numbers. Thus, it is enough to consider the case where $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: @fvel "If it could be written as two non-coprime numbers, that would be equivalent to being possible to write it as two coprime numbers"(this is a proof by contradiction). This is exactly how I understand it, but then why the book doesn't mention this fact. Is it too trivial to be mentioned?

Comment: @user31782 Examples: $\frac{12}{16}$ can be reduced to $\frac{3}{4}$, and this is true for all non-coprime numbers. Thus if it can't be written as fraction of coprime numbers, it cannot be written as a fraction with non-coprime numbers. E.g. if it cannot be written as $\frac{1}{2}$ it cannot be written as $\frac{12}{16}$ nor any reducible fraction of the form $\frac{1\times k}{2\times k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. And yes it is trivial, although nothing can ever be too trivial not to question.

Comment: @user31782: 'Reduction $\dfrac{a}{b}$ into lowest terms' means formation of the fraction $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)}$.

Answer (score 6):

What is a rational number? The definition I use is that it's a number that can be written as a ratio of two integers. If your book doesn't say explicitly that the integers can be coprime, it's because the notion of a reduced fraction is fundamental to working with fractions. You're not allowed to work with fractions until you believe that they can be written in a unique reduced form, and that your numerator and denominator will be coprime.

If you wanted to, you can prove this with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Suppose your rational number $q$ can be written as the ratio of integers $\frac{a}{b}$. Then by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $a$ and $b$ have unique factorizations into primes. So factorize them, and the factors that appear in both will cancel. Then you have a coprime numerator and denominator.

In the proof that you're trying, I don't see the need for contradiction. Statement **X** and **Y** imply each other. If you have a ratio of non-coprime numbers, reduce it. If you have a ratio of coprime numbers, multiply them both by 2 and now you have a ratio of non-coprime numbers. (The statements you have written are the contrapositive of this.)

Comment: How X directly implies Y?  Do you mean that X can be reduced to Y without any proof?

Comment: Whether or not something requires proof depends on the reader. If you can agree with me that the contrapositive of a statement is logically equivalent to the statement, then in my last paragraph, I've proved that X implies Y.

Comment: Actually I heard the term "contrapositive" for the first time. I will reply you soon once I read about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me the term _contrapositive_. Had I read about it before I would not have ask any question. The wikipedea page specifically answer what my questions is, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition#Application

Comment: Yes, that section is very relevant to your original question!

Answer (score -1):

Let $\sqrt2 = a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are not co-prime, that is they have a common divisor greater than or equal to $2$, so let $d = gcd(a, b)$, $a’=a/d$, $b’=b/d$. Now $a’/b’ = a/b = \sqrt2$, and $a’$, $b’$ are co-prime.